# Generic function to byte swapping a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, endianness

I know one way to byte swap a struct is to byte swap each individual member variables separately.

Below is an example.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<byteswap.h>

   #define Uint16 unsigned short int
   #define Uint32 unsigned int
   
   typedef struct {
      Uint16 num16_1;
      Uint16 num16_2;
      Uint32 num32_1;
      Uint16 num16_3;
      char   ch_1;
      char   ch_2;
      Uint32 num32_2;
   }TestStruct;

   void InitTestStruct(TestStruct* buffer) {

      buffer->num16_1 = (Uint16) 0x1234;
      buffer->num16_2 = (Uint16) 0x5678;
      buffer->num32_1 = (Uint32) 0x56781234;
      buffer->num16_3 = (Uint16) 0x4321;

      buffer->ch_1 = 'a';
      buffer->ch_2 = 'b';

      buffer->num32_2 = (Uint32) 0x12345678;
   }

   void SwapTestStruct(TestStruct* buffer) {

      buffer->num16_1 = bswap_16(buffer->num16_1);
      buffer->num16_2 = bswap_16(buffer->num16_2 );
      buffer->num32_1 = bswap_32(buffer->num32_1 );
      buffer->num16_3 = bswap_16(buffer->num16_3 );

      //ch_1; /* chars do not need byte swapping */
      //ch_2; /* chars do not need byte swapping */

      buffer->num32_2 = bswap_32(buffer->num32_1);
   }
   
   void PrintTestStruct(TestStruct buffer) {

      printf("********************************************\n");
      printf("buffer.num16_1 - [%04x]\n", buffer.num16_1);
      printf("buffer.num16_2 - [%04x]\n", buffer.num16_2);
      printf("buffer.num32_1 - [%04x]\n", buffer.num32_1);
      printf("buffer.num16_3 - [%04x]\n", buffer.num16_3);
      printf("buffer.ch_1    - [%c]\n",   buffer.ch_1);
      printf("buffer.ch_2    - [%c]\n",   buffer.ch_2);
      printf("buffer.num32_2 - [%04x]\n", buffer.num32_2);
      printf("********************************************\n");
}

   int main(void) {

      TestStruct tstruct;

      InitTestStruct(&tstruct);   /* Initialize the TestStruct */

      PrintTestStruct(tstruct);
      
      SwapTestStruct(&tstruct);   /* Byte swap the TestStruct */

      PrintTestStruct(tstruct);

      return 0;
   }
```

I'm trying to see if there is a way to byte swap a struct without knowing the actual struct definitions.

1. Like, to get the offset of the 1st member variable of the struct, byte swap it.
2. Then get the offset of the 2nd member and byte swap it.
3. Repeat this process till the last member is byte swapped.

This way, a single function would be good enough to byte swap any struct irrespective of the definitions.

Is there any library already available which does this?

An example:
I'm trying to implement something like

```
typedef struct {
   int num1;
   int num2;
}TestStruct1;

typedef struct {
   int num1;
   int num2;
   int num3;
}TestStruct2;

typedef struct {
   int num1;
   int num2;
   int num3;
   int num4;
}TestStruct3;

void bswap_struct(void* any_struct); /* one single function to byte swap any struct in the world */

int main(void) {

   TestStruct1 tstruct1;
   TestStruct2 tstruct2;
   TestStruct3 tstruct3;

   /* Code to initialize tstruct1, tstruct2, tstruct3 */
   tstruct1 = { 0x1234, 0x5678 };
   tstruct2 = { 0x2345, 0x6789, 0x7890 };
   tstruct3 = { 0x1234, 0x5678, 0x3456, 0x8901 };

   /* byte swap all structs */
   bswap_struct(&tstruct1);
   bswap_struct(&tstruct2);
   bswap_struct(&tstruct3);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define Uint16 unsigned short int`?!?!  Don't ever `#define` types, especially not when you're just mirroring [standard types](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20)

Comment: structs carry no information about the offsets and sizes of their elements.

Comment: In order to know which bytes of the structure to move around, you need to know at least the sizes of the members. The C standard does not provide any way to get the sizes of the members of a structure without their names.

Comment: @stark: “No information” is excessive. If the structure is 16 bytes, we have information that no member is larger than 16 bytes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That information is not carried in the struct.

Answer (score 3):

> if there is a way to byte swap a struct without knowing the actual struct definitions.

No, C programming language does not have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming). You, the programmer, have to tell the program what types have been used.

---

With some _Generic and preprocesor FOREACH macro you can get away with just listing member names of the structure, like below. I do not think I would write such code - I would most probably leave the code as you presented, because it is more readable and easier to debug and understand and allows IDE "rename" features to work properly.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <byteswap.h>

#define FOREACH_1(f,c,a)     f(c,a)
#define FOREACH_2(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_1(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_3(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_2(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_4(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_3(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_5(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_4(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_6(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_5(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_7(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_6(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_8(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_7(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_9(f,c,a,...) f(c,a) FOREACH_8(f,c,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_N(_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)  FOREACH##N
#define FOREACH(f,ctx,...)  FOREACH_N(__VA_ARGS__,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1)(f,ctx,__VA_ARGS__)

#define BSWAP_STRUCT_ONE(var, memb)  _Generic((var->memb), \
    char: 0, \
    uint8_t: 0, \
    uint16_t: (var->memb = bswap_16(var->memb)), \
    uint32_t: (var->memb = bswap_32(var->memb)));
#define BSWAP_STRUCT(var, ...)  FOREACH(BSWAP_STRUCT_ONE, var, __VA_ARGS__)

typedef struct {
    uint16_t num16_1;
    uint16_t num16_2;
    uint16_t num32_1;
    uint16_t num16_3;
    char   ch_1;
    char   ch_2;
    uint32_t num32_2;
} TestStruct;

void SwapTestStruct(TestStruct* buffer) {
    BSWAP_STRUCT(
        buffer,
        num16_1,
        num16_2,
        num32_1,
        num16_3,
        ch_1,
        ch_2,
        num32_2
    )
}
```

Comment: It is not very generic. It will not work for any data size.

Answer (score 1):

Generic I would do something like this:

```
#define GETSIZE(type, memb) sizeof((type){0,}.memb)
#define BSWAPMEMBER(ptr, type, memb) bswap(ptr, offsetof(type, memb), GETSIZE(type, memb))

typedef struct {
    uint16_t num16_1;
    uint16_t num16_2;
    uint64_t num64_1;
    char   ch_1;
    char   ch_2;
    __int128 i128;
} TestStruct;

void *bswap(void *ptr, const size_t offset, const size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *start = ptr;
    unsigned char *end;

    if(ptr && size)
    {
        start += offset;
        end = start + size - 1;
        while(start < end)
        {
            unsigned char temp = *start;
            *start++ = *end;
            *end-- = temp;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}

void print(const void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    const unsigned char *ucp = ptr;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index ++)
        printf("0x%hhX ", *ucp++);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    TestStruct str = {.num64_1 = 0x1122334455667788ULL};
    unsigned char testarr[] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44, 0x55,0x66, 0x77,0x88,0x99,0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0xff};
    memcpy(&str.i128, testarr, sizeof(testarr));

    print(&str.i128, sizeof(str.i128));
    BSWAPMEMBER(&str, TestStruct, i128);
    print(&str.i128, sizeof(str.i128));

    print(&str.num64_1, sizeof(str.num64_1));
    BSWAPMEMBER(&str, TestStruct, num64_1);
    print(&str.num64_1, sizeof(str.num64_1));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aqa4qrY61

Or if you use gcc or really new C standard

```
#define BSWAPMEMBER(ptr, memb) bswap(ptr, offsetof(typeof(*(ptr)), memb), GETSIZE(typeof(*(ptr)), memb))
```

```
int main(void)
{
    TestStruct str = {.num64_1 = 0x1122334455667788ULL};
    unsigned char testarr[] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x55,0x66, 0x77,0x88,0x99,0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0xff};
    memcpy(&str.i128, testarr, sizeof(testarr));

    print(&str.i128, sizeof(str.i128));
    BSWAPMEMBER(&str, i128);
    print(&str.i128, sizeof(str.i128));

    print(&str.num64_1, sizeof(str.num64_1));
    BSWAPMEMBER(&str, num64_1);
    print(&str.num64_1, sizeof(str.num64_1));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4xEMMcrcd

It will work with any size members (for example an array)
https://godbolt.org/z/cn9G7jWav

Comment: `#define BSWAPMEMBER(ptr, type, memb) bswap(ptr, offsetof(type, memb), GETSIZE(type, memb))`


This again requires the programmer to know the struct definitions.

Comment: For clarity, I added an example at the end of the question.